# What is difference between derivative in standard and non standard analysis?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I am reading the book on complex analysis by Tristan Needham. In that book he explains derivative in an intuitive way as a quantity by which  dx is expanded to get dy in both complex and real number plane.
But In non standard analysis, derivative is defined in other way,
Sh[(f(x+dx)-f(x)/dx)]=sh(dy/dx) where 'sh' denotes the shadow function
Now is the definition of derivative given in the book of Tristan needham false, Because of the shadow function according to non standard analysis?
In simple words my question is what is intuitive definition of derivative as given in book of Tristan needham according to non standard analysis?

Comment: I am sorry if I had not explained my question well.

Comment: Nonstandard analysis has a very technical foundation, requiring experience in logic and/or set theory. From a very, very high bird's eye view, though, the standard derivative is the same as the nonstandard derivative; they're two different languages for describing the same thing.

Comment: So is it  too complicated to  answer my question?

Comment: To give a thorough answer, probably. The takeaway, I think, is that once nonstandard analysis is put on firm footing, the two definitions of the derivative are describing two sides of the same coin. As you progress through the book, you'll find a really common transformation of the complex plane, the Mobius transformation. As it turns out, it's natural to put infinity into that as well, and provides a different perspective of the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition for the derivative in Needham's [Visual Complex Analysis](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/visual-complex-analysis-9780198534464) is intuition, and so it is independent of the formal definition. Since the formal definition of the derivative in non-standard analysis is logically equivalent to the formal definition in standard analysis, Needham's intuition applies equally well.

**Edit:**
Specifically, for $u$ that depends on $x$ but not on $y$, Needham (paraphrased) writes the following, using "infinitesimal" in an informal way.

> …an infinitesimal…$dx$ the infinitesimal [displacement] $du$…$du=$ total change in $u$ due to moving along $dx$ $=$ (rate of change of $u$ with $x$)$\cdot$(change $dx$ in $x$) $=(\partial u/\partial x)dx$

This is reminiscent of the definition of the derivative in nonstandard analysis: If $dx$ is an infinitesimal (now used formally) change in $x$, and $u=f(x)$, then the corresponding change in $u$ is $du:={}^*f(x+dx)-{}^*f(x)$, and we have $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\mathrm{sh}\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)$ when the left side is defined.

Comment: Mark S,   I don't see the definition of standard and non standard analysis being the same. But can you please elaborate explaining how Needham's intuition works for non standard definition of derivative?

Comment: @Rahul The definitions are certainly not the same. But they're logically equivalent, as mentioned in [the Wikipedia article for nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis#First_consequences); the original aim of nonstandard analysis was to give an equivalent foundation for analysis. — Needham's intuition is extremely similar to the nonstandard definition of the derivative, as I've edited above.

Comment: @Rahul Let me know if there's anything I've misunderstood or anything more I could do to make this answer helpful to you.

Comment: @Rahul you can prove it's equivlaence through something called Model Theory. There was an interview on a woman in model theory in the numberphile video channel where they talk exactly of this